# How can I format an integer to have two decimals?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How to format an integer to have two decimals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14197319/how-to-format-an-integer-to-have-two-decimals)

I am struggling with this piece of code here.

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("00.##");
df.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
return df.format(Integer.valueOf(amount));
```

Here's what I need:

> Input: 2, Output: 2.00
>
> Input 20, Output: 20,00
>
> Input 1003, Output: 100,30
>
> Input 120323, Output: 1.203,23 (a thousand two hundred and three and twenty three cents)

I can't use DecimalFormat because I don't have a pattern "example ##.##".

I should always have two decimals. If the amount is less that 100, then I only have to take the amount itself and add ".00" If it is bigger than 100, means that the two last digits are the two decimals I need. They are the cents.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You're mixing `,` and `.` in the output, which is it? Should 2 => "2.000" or "2,00"?

Comment: That's a repost of your 15 min old question. You say "_If the amount is less that 100_...", sounds like you also need that if in your code.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to add two decimal places (which will always be `.00` which is a bit redundant.

```
return String.format("%.2f", amount > 100 ? amount/100.0 : (double) amount);
```

I suggest you keep one set of units.  You should be able to always use cents. If you don't do this you are likely to get confusion. For example, you have 100 and 10000 which are both 100.00

Comment: do You really mean `ammount/100` (double m)? :)

Comment: That worked great, Peter.
I myself told "if the value is less than 100" and I didnt add that to the algorithm. Thanks for showing me the way. Cheers

Comment: Thank you @fdiv_bug. I have changed it to keep the format consistent.

Answer (score 1):

> If the amount is less that 100, then I only have to take the amount
>   itself and add ".00" If it is bigger than 100, means that the two last
>   digits are the two decimals I need.

First you need to fix this problem.  A class, or a native type, should only hold one kind of data, and should not burden other classes or code with detailed knowledge of how that data is to be handled *depending on circumstances*.

Get that thing to either return back numbers of pennies **in all cases**, or get it to return a number that supports decimal points.  The better solution is numbers of pennies.

That way you don't have to put logic in your formatting, which certainly won't be there the second time you need to format the same thing.

Comment: That would be great. But I can't ask for a whole organization who's been using this quite old system for years to change their data representation because I can't work with it.
Thanks you :)

Comment: You can always wrap old code into new interfaces.  Check out "Working Effectively With Legacy Code" by Feathers.  Even if you don't use all of the techniques in that book for your current situation, the exposure to them will have numerous benefits.

Comment: Hi @Edwin Buck. Thanks for the tip, I will definitely make sure to take a look on it.